# Enquiry on a property of separable set

Tags: general-topology

If a set is separable then it has countable bases. But what about converse??. If a set has countable bases is it separable.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Second Countable, First Countable, and Separable Spaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191923/second-countable-first-countable-and-separable-spaces)

Comment: What makes you think that if a set is separable it has a countable base?

Answer (score 1):

A topological space (not a set) is called separable iff it has a countable dense subset. Countable means not-uncountable, that is, finite or countably infinite.

A topological space is called second-countable iff it has a countable base. A space can be separable without being second-countable. There are many examples.

If a space is second-countable then it is separable. Because if $B$ is a countable base, then for each non-empty $b\in B$ choose $f(b)\in b$.  Every non-empty open set $S$ has some non-empty $b\in B$ as a subset, so $S$ has $f(b)$ as a member. So the countable set $D=\{f(b): \phi\ne b\in B\}$ intersects every non-empty open set, so $D$ is dense.

There  are many other interesting cardinals associated with a topology. They are referred to as topological cardinal functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let R have the base { {0,r} : r in R }.